# Who is the guy that found the 'X' badge at the beginning of X-Men: Days Of Future Past?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

At the very start of *X-Men: Days of Future Past*, we see a white-haired person with a modern-looking flashlight come across an X-Men belt buried in the dirt.

Who is he?

[image]

Comment: Flashlights don't yet look so cool in the modernity around *me*.

Comment: @Praxis People are boring.  [Buy online](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00PJOAHQE?psc=1).

Comment: @Izkata : *Nothing was the same*.

Comment: Guy looks like an Engineer from Prometheus. With hair.

Comment: He is also in Apocalypse. I think the actor is related to the director or something.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[IMDB Trivia](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1877832/trivia?item=tr2209481) indicates that he's [Nate Grey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nate_Grey) (Scott and Jean's son) however I've not been able to locate the source of this piece of trivia, nor is there any explanation how this occurred, given that she died in the prior film.

> *According to Simon Kinberg, the mutant scavenger is Nate Grey, the
>   X-Man.*

[image]

At the very least, we can strongly assume that he's a mutant since he also appears (briefly) at the end of the film when Wolverine walks out of his futuristic bedroom at the X-Mansion:

[image]

His inclusion was likely intended as more of a nod/easter-egg to hardcore comic fans. The character <s>receives no billing in the cast list</s> is listed in the extended credits as "*[Young Mutant Scavenger](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Mutant_Scavenger)*", evidently played by Alexander Felici.

Answer (score 17):

According to an [IMDb trivia item](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1877832/trivia?item=tr2209481), the producer, Simon Kinberg, confirmed his identity:

> According to Simon Kinberg, the mutant scavenger is Nate Grey, the X-Man.

IMDb is a bit unreliable though, and I’ve been unable to find the interview with Kinberg where he said this. (Plenty of sites have repeated it verbatim though.)

In the comics, Grey is the biological son of Scott Summers (aka Cyclops) and Jean Grey, but it’s not clear if that would be the case in the cinematic universe.

Comment: Yeah... I dont remember they had a child. Any logic behind this that might explain ?

Comment: @FadhNhz In at least one storyline, Nate was created from their genetic material rather than a natural conception: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nate_Grey#Age_of_Apocalypse

Comment: `but I don’t see how that could be the case in the film universe.` weirder things have happened lol

Comment: Also, x-man has Cross-dimensional teleportation as a power at various points.

Comment: I thought Nate was the son of Scott & Madelyne Pryor (a clone of Jean Grey)?

Comment: @kylekanos Nathan "Nate" Summers aka cable was Scott and Maddie kid, sent to the future after Apocalypse won. Nathaniel Nate Grey aka the X Man is Scott and Jeans test tube baby that was created in the age of apocalypse world that was created inside the dark phoenix saga. They aren't the same people. Generic Brothers at best

Comment: @cde: Aha, that clears things up. Thank you.

Comment: Nate Grey is NOT Scott and Jean's son! He is the product of there enhanced DNA. Mr. Sinister created him in the X-Men: Alpha story arc. However him being the most powerful being in that "Alternate" Universe when the reality shifted back to normal he was able to cross over into normal continuity.

Answer (score 0):

If this mutant is in fact Nathaniel Grey, then because of his abilities and powers he may have been able to remember - as did logan - the war the destruction and aftermath.

There is a specific reason why Logan was shown to regard this mutant with slight surprise and a reason that Nathaniel was featured at the end of future past.

Perhaps logan smelled or sensed jean or scott in the boy and thought  surprisingly "did Jean and scott have a child?" Nathaniel's appearance may be a harbinger to introducing the next movie storyline or newly introduced mutants

Answer (score -2):

I think it's Longshot. That would explain the extraordinary millisecond save from certain death at the end of the movie and the generally great and lucky outcome for the him and as a result, the X-men. Sending back Logan was a longshot, and it worked.

Comment: Interesting answer, but how is this going to prove that it's *not* Nate Grey? as the previous answers have shown?